# From Windows, use Expect and plink to execute standard commands on remote Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, tcl, expect, plink

I want to connect to a distant Linux machine trough ssh (with primary key and passphrase) and execute commands on that remote machine. The goal is to make some recurrent tasks faster.

I use plink (putty link) to connect with SSH and TCL (with Expect installed) to send commands to my linux server.
But nothing works! When I execute the following script, nothing happens. Not an error, not a line, nothing. Just the word "begin" until the timeout expires.
But if I write "plink sessionName" in the console directly I have the response of the linux server, I can enter my passphrase and control the remote machine.

```
package require Expect

exp_send "begin\n"
exp_spawn plink sessionName
exp_send "end\n"
expect "Using username \root\".\nPassphrase for key \"imported-openssh-key\": "
```

Thank you in advance for helping me :)

Comment: Don't `exp_send` before `exp_spawn`. What does `puts [auto_execok plink]` report?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response !

Sorry for the delay, the stackoverflow e-mail went to a folder I never open (thanks gmail...).

Ok, I won't use exp_send before exp_spawn anymore.
For the command "puts [auto_execok plink]" it returns the correct location of the program plink.EXE
The .exe should be lowercase, but I doubt it is the problem.

I probably need to know much more about tcl.